# How to randomly pair items in a list

Tags: perl, random, shuffle

I have a list of Accession numbers that I want to pair randomly using a Perl script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my $file = 'randomseq_acc.txt';

my @identifiers = map { (split /\n/)[1] } <$file>; 

chomp @identifiers;

#Shuffle them and put in a hash 

@identifiers = shuffle @identifiers; 

my %pairs = (@identifiers);

#print the pairs

for (keys %pairs) { 
    print "$_ and $pairs{$_} are partners\n";
```

but keep getting errors.

The accession numbers in the file `randomseq_acc.txt` are:

```
1094711
1586007
2XFX_C
Q27031.2
P22497.2
Q9TVU5.1
Q4N4N8.1
P28547.2
P15711.1
AAC46910.1
AAA98602.1
AAA98601.1
AAA98600.1
EAN33235.2
EAN34465.1
EAN34464.1
EAN34463.1
EAN34462.1
EAN34461.1
EAN34460.1
```

Comment: Can you post what are errors you getting?

Comment: And also you have not open your file for reading. you should use a filehandle.

Comment: @toolic : I didn't change the code in the OP.

Comment: It was "invisible" because of wrong formatting. Check the markdown in the diff.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add the closing right curly brace to be able to compile the script.

As arrays are indexed from 0,  `(split /\n/)[1]` returns the *second* field, i.e. what follows newline on each line (i.e. nothing). Change it to `[0]` to make it work:

```
my @identifiers = map { (split /\n/)[0] } <$file>; # Still wrong.
```

The diamond operator needs a file handle, not a file name. Use `open` to associate the two:

```
open my $FH, '<', $file or die $!;
my @identifiers = map { (split /\n/)[0] } <$FH>;
```

Using `split` to remove a newline is not common. I'd probably use something else:

```
map { /(.*)/ } <$FH>
# or
map { chomp; $_ } <$FH>
# or, thanks to ikegami
chomp(my @identifiers = <$FH>);
```

So, the final result would be something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my $filename = '...';
open my $FH, '<', $filename or die $!;

chomp(my @identifiers = <$FH>);

my %pairs = shuffle(@identifiers);
print "$_ and $pairs{$_} are partners\n" for keys %pairs;
```

Comment: More efficient: `chomp( my @identifiers = <$FH> );`